# Find the index of duplicate values and add the values at those index positions in a differnt list

Tags: python

Okay this is a bit complicated. I have two lists

list1= [sdfd, dfd, wer, abg, cccc]

list2= [11, 3, -11, 15, 3]

As you can see each list1 value has a corresponding list 2 value. I need to find the duplicates in list1, then add their corresponding numbers in list2. So in this instance 10 and -1. Replace value in list2 that corresponds with the last occurring duplicate in list1, so in this case insert 9 in place of -1 in list 2. Then I can use update to build a dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What are you having trouble with? This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to understand.

Comment: Your question is "How do I..." rather than "What am I doing wrong here:"  So your question looks more like: "Code this problem for me.".  That being said, I would probably use the zip function to get a list of tuples, then cycle through that list, creating a dictionary as you go, creating dictionary entries or adding to them.  Enough hints.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the indices of each `key` in `list1` -

```py
string_positions = defaultdict(list)

for i, string in enumerate(list1):
  string_positions[string].append(i)
```

Once you have this populated, you can just use it and modify `list2` -

```py
for indices in string_positions.values():
  list2[indices[-1]] = sum(list2[i] for i in indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over list1 and keep track of the duplicate value in a `dict()` as you go:

```
list1 = ['asdf', 'jkl', 'asdf', 'foobar', 'bbbb']
list2 = [10, 3, -1, 17, 17]

seen = {}
for idx, item in enumerate(list1):
    if val := seen.get(item):
        list2[idx] += val
    else:
        seen[item] = list2[idx]

print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[10, 3, 9, 17, 17]
```

Note: Python 3.8+ with the := (walrus operator)...